# Фестиваль документального кино «КрымДок»... Может ли писаться слитно?

Tags: выбор-слов

Фестиваль документального кино «КрымДок»... Может ли писаться слитно, или лучше через дефис?

Answer (score 1):

Слитно - может (комсомол, Петмол - петербургская молочная компания и т. п.), а вот *заглавные* буквы в середине слова недопустимы по определению (есть лишь курьёзные случаи регистрации таких названий).

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, сейчас такие названия уже далеко не единичны, хотя по правилам русского языка вроде бы не должно быть прописной буквы в середине слова. Но ведь допускаются сочетания строчных и прописных:

> Сложносокращенные слова со значением собственного имени, образованные
>   частично из начальных звуков, частично из усеченных слов, пишутся в
>   первой части прописными буквами, во второй — строчными: ВНИИстрой-
>   дормаш (Всесоюзный научно-исследовательский институт дорожного
>   машиностроения), НИИхиммаш (Научно-исследовательский институт
>   химического машиностроения). Но если аббревиатура находится в середине
>   или в конце сложносокращенного слова, то она чаще пишется строчными
>   буквами: Гипродорнии, Промтрансниипро- ект. Вместе с тем возможно
>   написание аббревиатуры с прописной буквы, например:
>   ПромтрансНИИпроект, ГипродорНИИ, микроЭВМ, суперЭВМ.

https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/bukvennyie-abbreviaturyi-slojnosokraschennyie-70718.html

РосНИИ — Российский научно-исследовательский институт

БелАЗ — Белорусский автомобильный завод

И по правилам или нет, но такое название *фестиваль документального кино «КрымДок»* есть, это его официальное название.

http://xn--d1albglj1f.xn--p1ai/festival-2018/novosti/43-pervyj-krymskij-otkrytyj-festival-dokumentalnogo-kino-krymdok

Есть и такое: ПАО «МТС» (ПАО «Мобильные ТелеСистемы»).

А вот название сайта  -  КиберПедия.

Так что язык развивается, возможно, изменятся и правила, будут менее категоричны.